# Why is the encoding for recentfile save file set to utf-8 rather than plain text?

Tags: character-encoding, recentf, utf-8

This is from `recentf.el` in Emacs 26.3:

```lisp
    (defconst recentf-save-file-coding-system
      (if (coding-system-p 'utf-8-emacs)
          'utf-8-emacs
        'emacs-mule)
      "Coding system of the file `recentf-save-file'.")
```

Why is it set to utf-8 rather than plain text?

Is it to support the extended character set in file paths & file names or is there something more?

Encountered this when I wanted to use `sed` to do a clean-up of my `.recentf` file.  I wanted to remove many entries using a regexp and `sed` from the command line when Emacs is not running.  `sed` silently does not do the right thing (no deletion of lines) and I think it's because of the encoding.

Comment: Unless you find some comment about this in the file `recentf.el` you might need to ask Emacs developers, by sending mail to `emacs-devel@gnu.org`. In any case, you likely don't want to use `emacs-mule`. Maybe another question is why this is a `defconst`, not a `defvar` or even a `defcustom`. In principle this means that the program needs (expects) it to be `utf-8` or `emacs-mule`. `defconst` indicates that neither the program nor people should change the value.

Comment: `sed` can deal with utf-8 so I would suggest you post the command you use and a portion of the file that does not respond the way you expect. But since this has nothing to do with Emacs, I suggest you ask in [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).